# DbContext with Testcontainers and WebApplication factory not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing, testcontainers, asp.net-core-8

I'm trying to setup Testcontainers with SQL Server in order to create / run integration tests. My application is ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 8), and I'm using xUnit.

Here is my `WebApplicationFactory` code:

```cs
public class IntegrationTestWebAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly MsSqlContainer _dbContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
        .WithPassword("Strong_password_123!")
        .Build();

    public Task InitializeAsync() => _dbContainer.StartAsync();

    public new Task DisposeAsync() => _dbContainer.StopAsync();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) =>
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            Type descriptorType = typeof(DbContextOptions<SpendCentricContext>);

            ServiceDescriptor? descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == descriptorType);

            if (descriptor is not null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddTransient<ITimeProvider, MockTimeProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<ITenantService, MockTenantService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICorrelationIdProvider, MockCorrelationIdProvider>();

            string? connString = _dbContainer.GetConnectionString();
            services.AddDbContext<SpendCentricContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
        });
}
```

Connection works ok, and container is up and running after this step. Next class is just to handle disposing of resources:

```cs
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase : IClassFixture<IntegrationTestWebAppFactory>, IDisposable
{
    protected readonly IServiceScope scope;
    private readonly SpendCentricContext _dbContext;

    protected IntegrationTestBase(IntegrationTestWebAppFactory factory)
    {
        scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();

        _dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SpendCentricContext>();
        _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext?.Dispose();
        scope?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And finally seed class where this issue can be caught:

```cs
private async Task SeedTestData()
{
    var account = new Account
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse("faa3bfb3-42d7-4796-e701-08d9aff85e7f"),
        Name = "Banca Intesa",
        Description = "Intesa",
        AccountNumber = "",
        AccountCurrency = new Currency("EUR"),
        UserId = Guid.Parse("f9caa978-2ccc-4837-945f-dbc45ae83f72"),
        AccountType = AccountType.Bank,
        IsDefault = true,
        DateCreated = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1),
        DateUpdated = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1),
        IsDeleted = false,
        Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>()
    };

    IAccountRepository accountRepository = scope.ServiceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<IAccountRepository>();

    var result = await accountRepository.AddAccount(account);
    var current = await accountRepository.GetAccounts();
}
```

So now comes strange part: result is not null, entity is saved without any issues, or at least, there is no exception on `SaveChangesAsync`. Also, when I open table in SQL client, entity is perfectly fine saved there. But on the next line, nothing is returned,`current` is empty collection (code behind is simple `ToListAsync`).

**UPDATE**: added repo implementation:

```cs
public sealed class AccountRepository(SpendCentricContext dbContext, ILogger logger) : IAccountRepository
{
    public async Task<Account> AddAccount(Account account)
    {
        EntityEntry<Account> accountEntry = await dbContext.Accounts.AddAsync(account);
        return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() == 1
            ? accountEntry.Entity
            : throw new ArgumentException(nameof(account));
    }

    public async Task<Account> GetAccount(Guid id, bool includeTransactions = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Account> account = dbContext.Accounts.AsNoTracking();
            if (includeTransactions)
                account.Include(x => x.Transactions);

            return await account.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "Error getting account with id: {Id}", id);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone played with Testcontainers and maybe bumped into a similar issue?

Comment: Can you please share the implementation of `IAccountRepository`?

Comment: updated with impl

Comment: IIRC you need to replace (remove) the `DbConnection` too. Here is an old [guide](https://testcontainers.com/guides/testing-an-aspnet-core-web-app/). Today, I favor passing the connection string as [setting](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/examples/aspnet/#utilizing-webapplicationfactory) to the app (the first mentioned approach).